# Service method called in directive's controller runs but logs undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a directive which is used in some of my templates and handles to upload a file, where I need to inject the relative service which handles the server requests.

Here it is

```
angular.module("app")

.directive('addFile', ['projectService', addFile]);

function addFile(projectService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/add_file_form.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', addFileCtrl]
    }

    function addFileCtrl($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $scope.upload = {
            //Some other properties

            post: function () {

                if ($scope.upload.selectedOption.type == 0) {
                    projectService.uploadFile($scope.upload.file, $stateParams.projectId).then(success, fail);

                    function success(res) {
                        console.log("Uploaded file with success");
                        $state.reload();
                    };

                    function fail(res) {
                        console.log("Failed to upload file");
                        console.log(res);
                    };
                } else {
                    projectService.uploadLink($scope.upload.link, $stateParams.projectId).then(success, fail);

                    function success(res) {
                        console.log("Uploaded file with success");
                        $state.reload();
                    };

                    function fail(res) {
                        console.log("Failed to upload file");
                        console.log(res);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though the request from projectService is done successfully my log says and eventually the success function isn't called:

> Error: projectService.uploadLink(...) is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was that I didn't return the promise on my service...

@Pankaj actually helped me to exclude that the problem wasn't on the directive itself.

Answer (score 1):

The dependency injected inside directive function would only be available inside directive link(preLink & postLink) function only.

If you want `projectService` in directive's controller then you have to inject in controller DI array & its respective controller factory function.

```
controller: ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'projectService', addFileCtrl]
```

and

```
function addFileCtrl($scope, $state, $stateParams, projectService) {
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Did that with no luck. It remains the same. Method from service runs, server request is completed successfully success function doesn't run since there is error `Error: projectService.uploadLink(...) is undefined`

Comment: @Korte have you added `projectService` in both place?

Comment: @Korte by looking at code, the changes seems perfect! it should work, try to refresh cache and check

Comment: The problem actually occurs when I add `.then(success,fail)` . If I remove I get no error at all. Why does that happen ??

Comment: Found the problem. I wasn't returning the promise from my service...fool of me :p

Comment: @Korte that's why I was asking about the service code, I'm about to update the answer, but you did added as an answer. Thanks :) I thought that I had helped you :(

Comment: @Korte let me know if you wanted to deleted my answer, I thought that real problem was your interpretation about injection of dependency in directive